# Position fixed content overlapping problem

Tags: css, html

This is my html5 markup

```
<div id="header">
</div>
<div id="content">
</div>
<div id="footer">
</div>
```

Now used css

```
header {
  height: 95px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 980px;
}

footer {
  background: #000000;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 980px
}
```

Now my problem is when i put any content inside

```
<div id="content">
</div>
```

The content comes from top:0 which is not required. I dont want to use padding or margin top over content. Is there any way from which content comes below header.

Comment: What's a `<content>` tag? Where did you get that idea from?

Comment: use write tag "<article>" instead of "<content>"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The main reason is because the `<header>` is `position:fixed` taking it out of the document flow. You'll need to add `margin` or `padding` to either the `<body>` or your `<content>`(??) element. Also, if using HTML5 elements, add this to the top of your CSS rules for compatibility with older browsers.

```
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
```

Taken from [Eric Meyer's CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

Answer (score 14):

Best solution use:

```css
position: sticky;
top: 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't mention any other layout requirements you may have, but this would be a good start

```
content {position: relative; top: 95px}
```

**Update**

As the other good people state, `<content>` is not a valid HTML5 tag. Maybe it doesn't have to do with the specific question, but do follow their advice and avoid rolling your own tags. Use a standard one instead.

Comment: I dont think you should be encouraging the OP to write his own custom tags.

Comment: @Starx: I 'm not encouraging anything. You and everyone else is right in saying "don't use `<content>`", but that would still not solve the OP's problem.

Comment: IMO the road to begin solving his problem, starts when he removes his `<content>` tag

Answer (score 2):

Follow those HTML5 tags, that are present. If you going to create your own, then that might have consequencies.

Here follow this.

```
<header>
</header>
<section>
</section>
<footer>
</footer>
```

To learn about valid HTML5 tags please follow this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it is reaaaaly simple.
Just use --> position: sticky;

Comment: ------------------------- And --> top: 0;

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please make sure to use the "Curly braces" tool in the editor to format your code snippet for better readability.

Answer (score 1):

I'm recently working on this topic and here is an implementation I found by inspecting [Dropbox's job website](https://www.dropbox.com/jobs/listing/1073973).

They use a dummy `div` right after the fixed `header` and set the height of this `div` the same as `header`'s.

Personally I prefer this solution as:

1. It's easier to make the dummy `div` height consistent with the `header` on different devices.
2. I can layout the `content` part as if the fixed header doesn't exist, which makes more sense to me.

Here is a demo:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.header-dummy {
  height: 150px; /* this height SHOULD always be at least the same as header's */
  background-color: chartreuse;
}

#content {
  background-color: orange;
}

footer {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <section>
    <div>
      <span>HEADER TEXT</span>
    </div>
  </section>
</header>
<div class="header-dummy"></div>
<div id="content">
  <h3>Content are not Impacted</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <h3>Content are not Impacted</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <h3>Content are not Impacted</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <h3>Content are not Impacted</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <h3>Content are not Impacted</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <h3>Content are not Impacted</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <h3>Content are not Impacted</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <h3>Content are not Impacted</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<footer>
  <span>I'm just a footer</span>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you don't actually mean `<content>`, as that isn't a valid HTML5 tag. Anyway, the problem you're seeing is down to the `position: fixed` directive for your `<header>` element. Try removing that and going from there.

Answer (score 0):

If other solutions don't work, check that your background/background-color is not transparent, and set it to white.

Answer (score 0):

So for what I get from this question, you are trying not to overlap stuff, you could use `z-index` inside your **div**'s css:

```
.example {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -10;
}
```

*`z-index` only works on positioned elements (`position:absolute`, `position:relative`, or `position:fixed`)*

Answer (score 0):

I tried many ways not working. finally I found.

```
.fixed-header{
     position: fixed;
     z-index: 1;        // Header comes front
}
```