# Overlapping dynamic fixed header

Tags: html, css, web

My fixed header is overlapping my content. 
Much like here ([Position fixed content overlapping problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311706/position-fixed-content-overlapping-problem))

but my header is dynamic so not always 50px in height sometimes 52, 100 ...

Comment: We are going to need some coding..

Comment: `<div style="postion: fixed; width: 100%; top: 0px;">Nav herer</div>
<div>Content here</div>`

Comment: I think this question needs a "javascript" tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to position it in your box better.

When you create a fixed element, it requires an **exact** position:

Example:

```
#header{ 
    height: 95px;
    width: 640px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 30px;
    right: 30px;
}
```

So, this is how your browser will read this: *I will place a fixed element in the top-right corner of the screen: 30 pixels from the top, and 30 pixels from the right of my screen.*

**THE REASON** those fixed elements are one on top of another it's because he didn't define a **top/bottom** and **left/right** position correctly. Add more text and you will see if you can scroll on the fixed elements (you can't..).

Put everything in a div and ID'it #bigBody. Give the #bigBody an exact width and height, let's say 1000 width and 600 height.
Now add these:

```
#header {
    height: 50px;
    width: 600px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 30px;
    right: 30px;
}

#footer {
    background: #fff;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 30px;
    width: 600px;
    position: fixed;
}
```

min-width is irrelevant here... you use this only if you design big websites that require multiple devices access like iPhones, Tablets etc... if your just playing with the code just stick with the basics.

Comment: Only the first elment is fixed the 2nd one is not

Comment: It's the same thing...

Define an exact position for the fixed element. Like Where should it be placed TOP or BOTTOM, now coming from where??? RIGHT or LEFT?

    #header{ 
    height: 50px;
    width: 600px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 30px;
    right: 30px;
    }

The other element requires an 'position: absolute' attribute. This attribute needs to be the child of a 'position: relative' attribute in order to work.

Comment: well i have `position: fixed;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
left: 0px;` on my header and `position: abolute` on my main content
still part of my main content is overlapped by the header. I also have tried `position: relative` on the content same result.

Comment: Your code is wrong. Place everything (header+content+footer) in a div and ID it #bigBody or whatever you want. Then #bigBody will have position: relative; and your header will now work properly. 


Basically when you set an absolute attribute the browser looks up the code and searches the parent of that element if it has relative attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that via JavaScript, updating both the size of the header and the margin of other widgets. See [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/djsbellini/ByvuH/2/) for an example (with CoffeeScript, tested on Firefox and Chrome), or [this other fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/djsbellini/3N7VE/1/) that uses jQuery. Basically it's changing the CSS together for more than one element.

```
header { height: value + "px"; }
.contents { margin-top: anotherValue + "px"; }
```

If the size change isn't done by JavaScript/CoffeeScript, you'll have to put a event listener to update the `.contents` CSS.

Comment: well i already did so 

`$("#mainContent").css("margin-top", $("#navbar").height() + 30);`
but a fallback would be great

Comment: As far as I know, there's no fallback for `margin-top` and `height`. If you mean a graceful degradation so that the jQuery version isn't enough, I'll suggest you to remove the `display: fixed;` for such a degradation fallback. Only in IE you can get the `onresize` event to work with elements (besides the window object), so you should choose to either add a trigger to an update function for every change that may affect the header height, or to use `setTimeout` and check/update that height periodically. I strongly suggest you to avoid a timer.

Comment: The header won't resizes unless the window does. That problem though is solved but. I thought of a non-javasctript fallback