# Position fixed div with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a problem with fixed positioned `div`, which overlap the 2nd element.

How to make the `fill` element fill the remaining space and not be overlapped by the `fixed`?.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: flex-start;
}

.container .fixed {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: aquamarine;
  z-index: 2;
}

.container .fill {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2500px;
  background: orange;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="fixed">
    Fixed content
  </div>
  <div class="fill">
    Remaining space
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is working [codepen demo](https://codepen.io/baagii95/pen/KZMKzJ)

Comment: unclear!! what do you want to achieve?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311706/position-fixed-content-overlapping-problem/47296574#47296574

Comment: what exactly you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is mainly 3 things to do to make your code sample work:

- When using percent for the height (on `container`), also its ascendants need a height

  *Optionally, instead of adding `height: 100%` on `html/body`, one can use viewport units, and in this case `vh`, and change `height: 100%` on `container` to `height: 100vh`*
- Use correct `flex-direction` value, which for this, assuming they should be vertically stacked, should be `column`
- Add a top margin to the `fill` item, equal to the `fixed` item's  height

Stack snippet

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;                    /*  added  */
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;          /*  added  */
}

.container .fixed {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;                         /*  added, some browsers want this too  */
  top: 0;                          /*  added, some browsers want this too  */
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: aquamarine;
  z-index: 2;
}

.container .fill {
  width: 100%;
  /*height: 2500px;                    temp. removed  */
  background: orange;
  flex: 1;
  margin-top: 200px;               /*  added  */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="fixed">
    Fixed content
  </div>
  <div class="fill">
    Remaining space
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Updated based on a comment/script sample

If one have a dynamic height on the `fixed`, one can use a simple script, here using jQuery.

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Wdxrve)

Stack snippet

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   
   /*  get/set margin on page load  */
   $(".fill").css('margin-top', $(".fixed").height() + 'px')
  
   var btn = $("button");
   btn.on("click", function(event){
      $(".fixed").append("<div class=\"appended\">Hello</div>");
      /*  get/set margin  */
      $(".fill").css('margin-top', $(".fixed").height() + 'px')
   }); 
});
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.container .fixed {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background: aquamarine;
  z-index: 2;
}
.container .fixed button {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 0;
  background: #d7d7d7;
}
.container .fixed .appended {
  padding: 1em;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.container .fill {
  width: 100%;
  background: orange;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="fixed">
    Fixed content
    <button>Click to append some element</button>
  </div>
  <div class="fill">
    Remaining space
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if fixed div change it's height dynamically how i solve this ? Or it is impossible to get remaining space also my project inside fixed div some items dynamically added.

Comment: @E.Batgerel As a `fixed`, or `absolute`, positioned element it taken out of flow, it is not possible for any other element to relate to its size, other than using a script.

Comment: okay i understand

Comment: @E.Batgerel If the `fixed` gets dynamically added, you could use the same script to also dynamically add its height as margin to, in this case the `fill` element

Comment: @E.Batgerel If my answer were helpful enough, please also accept it, or let me know what I can adjust for it to be. (to accept, click the gray check mark at the left side of the answer)

Comment: i will change my pen and show you some example just give a moment

Comment: https://codepen.io/baagii95/pen/KZMKzJ Here is i updated my pen. And how i get margin from fixed div ?

Comment: @E.Batgerel Like this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Wdxrve

Comment: @E.Batgerel Also updated my answer